# Android Unable to read JSON from rest service

Tags: java, android, rest

I have a rest service  http://xxx.yy.zz.ww:5000/config/server_config/grant , that returns:

```
[
  {
    "address":"xxx.yy.zz.ww",
    "chat_port":"8010",
    "comm_hub_address":"192.168.137.38",
    "comm_hub_port":50000,
    "comm_hub_udp_beacon":"192.168.42.129",
    "mqtt_port":"1883",
    "rest_port":"8000"
  }
]
```

**I have confirmed that this service works by copy pasting url in the browser.**

I'm using a [Callable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Callable) and [Future](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Future) that will return a JSON string that another helper method will parse into actual attributes.

**Here is the relevant code snippet:**

```
      /**
         * Attempts to load in the JSPN server configuration info from RESTful web service else if there is a failure fall back on default embedded JSON config file.
         *
         * @return true on success, false on error
         */
        private boolean loadServerConfig() {
            boolean loaded = false;
            InputStream is = null;
            URL url = null;
            try {

                //lets get the path of rest service that has the config file
                String address = XYZApp.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.address);
                String restful_port = XYZApp.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.rest_port);
                String client_name = XYZApp.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.client_name);
                String protocol = XYZApp.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.protocol);
                //construct server_config_path
                String server_config_path = XYZApp.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.server_config_path);

                    url = new URL(protocol + "://" + address + ":" + restful_port + server_config_path + client_name);

                //lets execute an FutureTask (async task with a result, that blocks until result is returned).
                ExecutorService exService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
                Log.i(TAG, "making call to URL:" + url.toString());
                Future<InputStream> future = exService.submit(new GetJsonSettingsTask(url));
                is = future.get();
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (is!=null) {
                        try {
                            serverConfig = Util.readServerJsonStream(is);
                            Log.i(TAG, "Read confing file from URL:"+url.toString());
                        }
                        catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Error reading server config file: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try {
                            is = Util.scanForJson(getString(R.string.file_path), configFile);
                            serverConfig = Util.readServerJsonStream(is);
                            Log.i(TAG, "Read confing file from PATH:"+getString(R.string.file_path));
                        }
                        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to locate server config file: " + configFile);
                        }
                        catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Error reading server config file: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                    //clean up
                    if (is!=null) {
                        try {
                            is.close();

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    //check if property was loaded
                    if (serverConfig!=null) {
                        loaded = !serverConfig.address.isEmpty();
                    }
                    return loaded;
                }

            }//end loadServerConfig()



        class GetJsonSettingsTask implements Callable<InputStream> {

            private URL url = null;


            public GetJsonSettingsTask(URL url) {
                this.url = url;

            }

            public InputStream call() {
                InputStream in = null;
                try {

                    if (this.url != null)
                    {
                        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) this.url.openConnection();
                        httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(15);
                        httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(10);
                        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                        httpURLConnection.connect();
                        if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                            in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

                        }

                    }

                } catch (MalformedURLException exc) {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                } catch (java.net.UnknownHostException exc) {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException exc) {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                } catch (NullPointerException exc) {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (in != null) {
                        try {
                            in.close();
                        } catch (IOException exc) {
                            exc.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

                return in;
            }

        }//end of inner class GetJsonSettingsTask

//reads the inputstream and extracts JSON & attributes
public static ServerConfig readServerJsonStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        String address = "";
        String commHubAddress = "";
        String mqttPort = "";
        String restPort = "";
        String chatPort = "";
        String commHubUdpBeacon = "";
        String commHubPort = "";

        if (in == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Attempting to read null InputStream! Are storage permissions granted?");
        } else {
            try (JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"))) {
                reader.beginObject();
                while (reader.hasNext()) {
                    String name = reader.nextName();
                    switch (name) {
                        case "address":
                            address = reader.nextString();
                            break;
                        case "comm_hub_address":
                            commHubAddress = reader.nextString();
                            break;
                        case "mqtt_port":
                            mqttPort = reader.nextString();
                            break;
                        case "rest_port":
                            restPort = reader.nextString();
                            break;
                        case "chat_port":
                            chatPort = reader.nextString();
                            break;
                        case "comm_hub_udp_beacon":
                            commHubUdpBeacon = reader.nextString();
                            break;
                        case "comm_hub_port":
                            commHubPort = reader.nextString();
                            break;
                        default:
                            Log.w(TAG, "Unexcepted JSON field! Skipping value!");
                            break;
                    }
                }
                reader.endObject();
            }
        }

           return new ServerConfig(address, commHubAddress, mqttPort,
                restPort, chatPort, commHubUdpBeacon, commHubPort);
    }
```

What I have noticed that with connection & read timeouts set to 15 secs (actually should not even take more than 1 sec, in the browser its instant) the code just returns the InputStream as null, therefore affectingly timing out with an error or exception.

**When I comment out connection & read time outs, I get IOException:**

> 06-19 19:44:33.470 22675-22675/XYZ.wams.controller.core W/System.err: java.io.IOException: closed
>           at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:388)
>           at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:288)
>           at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:351)
>           at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:180)
>           at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
>           at android.util.JsonReader.fillBuffer(JsonReader.java:742)
>           at android.util.JsonReader.nextNonWhitespace(JsonReader.java:782)
>           at android.util.JsonReader.nextValue(JsonReader.java:695)
>           at android.util.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:334)
>           at android.util.JsonReader.expect(JsonReader.java:308)
>           at android.util.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:293)
>           at XYZ.wams.controller.core.helpers.Util.readServerJsonStream(Util.java:181)

**This IOException occurs in the readServerJsonStream(InputStream in) method**

Any thoughts?

Thanks a million!

Comment: Are you running inside an Emulator? Do you happen to have proxy enabled?

Comment: You are closing the input stream even before reading it
finally {
                    if (in != null) {
                        try {
                            in.close();
                        } catch (IOException exc) {
                            exc.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

Comment: @MikeHoltkamp, that was definitely an issue, however after removing the premature cleanup the InputStream is still closing?

Comment: @MikeHoltkamp, it seems I was closing it in another place too, thanks that was the right answer.